# vulkan vkQueuePresentKHR spend a lot of time?

Tags: vulkan

I want to test how long vkQueuePresentKHR will take. But I found a strange thing. 
The testing **shader** is a filter, it like this (please omit scrawling area in her face ^^):
[image]

My testing [code](https://github.com/lbknxy/vulkan_log/blob/master/code.cpp) .

```
...
long vSubmitE = MGetCurTimeStamp();
....
result = vkQueuePresentKHR(graphicsQueue, &presentInfo);
// present end time
long vPresentE = MGetCurTimeStamp();

// log time of vkQueuePresentKHR  had spent...
LOGE("vpresent time = %d ms", vPresentE - vSubmitE);
```

device : nexus6p . GPU : Adreno (TM) 430 . PresentMode : mailbox . swapchain imageCount = 4.

At first the time is very good :[file1](https://github.com/lbknxy/vulkan_log/blob/master/vpresent_FIFO_.log)
[image]

Then worse :[file1](https://github.com/lbknxy/vulkan_log/blob/master/vpresent_FIFO_.log)
[image]

Over a peroid of time, I run this application again, then I can not beleive my own eyes :[file2](https://github.com/lbknxy/vulkan_log/blob/master/five.log)

[image]

I don't know how to explain this , because I feel it's very weird. Please help or try to give some idea how to explain this phenomenon.

Today, I add vkQueueWaitIdle(queue) to synchronize vkQueuePresentKHR, waiting and  recording stop time until operations in queue have been finished.This time , I change VkPresent to FIFO.

It likes this :

```
...
long vSubmitE = MGetCurTimeStamp();
....
result = vkQueuePresentKHR(graphicsQueue, &presentInfo);

// wait until back from gpu.
vkQueueWaitIdle(graphicsQueue);

// present end time
long vPresentE = MGetCurTimeStamp();

// log time of vkQueuePresentKHR  had spent...
LOGE("vpresent time = %d ms", vPresentE - vSubmitE);
```

After ten minutes , I got this :[full file](https://github.com/lbknxy/vulkan_log/blob/master/syncVul.log)

```
...
11-23 15:29:09.690  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:09.742  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:09.815  vpresent time = 24 ms
11-23 15:29:09.913  vpresent time = 24 ms
11-23 15:29:09.941  vpresent time = 24 ms
11-23 15:29:10.116  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:10.190  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:10.242  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:10.276  vpresent time = 24 ms
11-23 15:29:10.654  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:10.855  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:10.936  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:11.217  vpresent time = 25 ms
11-23 15:29:11.290  vpresent time = 56 ms
11-23 15:29:11.383  vpresent time = 40 ms
11-23 15:29:11.427  vpresent time = 40 ms
11-23 15:29:11.516  vpresent time = 40 ms
11-23 15:29:11.561  vpresent time = 41 ms
11-23 15:29:11.606  vpresent time = 40 ms
11-23 15:29:11.743  vpresent time = 41 ms
11-23 15:29:11.830  vpresent time = 40 ms
11-23 15:29:11.965  vpresent time = 40 ms
11-23 15:29:12.097  vpresent time = 41 ms
11-23 15:29:12.142  vpresent time = 41 ms
11-23 15:29:12.277  vpresent time = 40 ms
...
```

**Still unbelievable** !

Comment: sounds like a driver bug...

Comment: @ratchetfreak , I don't think so.  I also measure the execution time of Opengl es2 on this device(I mean just replace vulkan with opengl es2 and keep the rest is same), but opengl time is stable : 3 ms~ 7ms ,  then,  opengl time is about 10ms after 10 or 20 minutes,only a minority of time over 20ms.

Comment: could still be a driver bug

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be throttling back the CPU/GPU for heat reasons. IMO, mailbox is a very bad choice for mobile applications, and shouldn't be used.

You could try enabling sustained performance mode (you're lucky you've got pretty much the one device in the world that supports it!) and see if that helps at all.

Comment: At first , I think it's heat reason, but opengl works well when phone is heat, check this file[opengl](https://github.com/lbknxy/vulkan_log/blob/master/OpenGL.log). "sustained performance mode" , do you mean : FIFO ?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#sustained_performance_api. Typically, when faced with a demanding game, a mobile device runs at a clock speed that it can't maintain, the CPU/GPU heat up, then the device has to slow down to prevent overheating. So you get e.g. 60fps for 10 minutes, then 15fps, with sustained performance mode you maybe get 30fps continuously. At least that's the theory.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried  ` Window.setSustainedPerformanceMode() ` , But the problem still have not been solved.

Comment: Did you try using FIFO instead of Mailbox? Mailbox seems a very bad choice for mobile, I'm surprised it's even exposed as an option.

Comment: Yes , I have checked and set  `presentMode = FIFO`.